# Working with Contentful Rich text with Jekll

Tags: jekyll, contentful

I'm trying to render a rich text field coming from Contentful into Jekyll.... but I can't get it to work. Has anyone had success with this? I already installed  https://github.com/contentful/rich-text-renderer.rb as a gem & plugin, but there aren't any directions to make it work with Jekyll.

I am able to get the first paragraph with  `{{ page.body.content[0].content[0].value }}` but clearly that's not the way. and `{{ page.body.content | rich_text }}` throws an error.

Anyone know how to get this to work?

here's the YML file if it helps

```html
- sys:
    id: 58za8Qb9b9ahqvxcTBTESb
    created_at: !ruby/object:DateTime 2022-05-30 06:05:14.325000000 Z
    updated_at: !ruby/object:DateTime 2022-05-30 17:45:38.289000000 Z
    content_type_id: blogPost
    revision: 8
  title: This is for you Christine
  link: this-is-for-you-christine
  short_description: A working blog using Contentful and Jekyll
  body:
    nodeType: document
    data: {}
    content:
    - nodeType: paragraph
      data: {}
      content:
      - nodeType: text
        value: 'Here it is... a wonderful thing. A headless static site-generated
          blog. My JAMstack, you ask: '
        marks: []
        data: {}
    - nodeType: unordered-list
      data: {}
      content:
      - nodeType: list-item
        data: {}
        content:
        - nodeType: paragraph
          data: {}
          content:
          - nodeType: text
            value: Contentful - CMS
            marks: []
            data: {}
      - nodeType: list-item
        data: {}
        content:
        - nodeType: paragraph
          data: {}
          content:
          - nodeType: text
            value: 'Github - repository, '
            marks: []
            data: {}
      - nodeType: list-item
        data: {}
        content:
        - nodeType: paragraph
          data: {}
          content:
          - nodeType: text
            value: 'Jekyll - SSG, '
            marks: []
            data: {}
      - nodeType: list-item
        data: {}
        content:
        - nodeType: paragraph
          data: {}
          content:
          - nodeType: text
            value: Netlify - hosting
            marks: []
            data: {}
      - nodeType: list-item
        data: {}
        content:
        - nodeType: paragraph
          data: {}
          content:
          - nodeType: text
            value: 'IDE - Gitpod '
            marks: []
            data: {}
    - nodeType: paragraph
      data: {}
      content:
      - nodeType: text
        value: The cost of running. ABSOLUTELY FREE! Time to set up... once I knew
          what to do, we won't discuss research time... but we can say I deserve another
          3-day weekend. Aside... learned that I can understand developers speaking
          in Portuguese... cause, yes, that's what it took! Anyway... time to set
          up... under an hour. You're welcome! Of course, you are asking why this
          is one large block paragraph? I still have to figure out displaying rich
          text.
        marks: []
        data: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that Contentful has a longText/Markdown option. So no need for rich text.